# Dropping "when" in an adverbial clause renders this sentence ungrammatical?

Tags: adverbials, omissibility

Please consider these sentences side by side:

1. **When** walking in a dark alley, ***you should*** be cautious.
2. **When** walking in a dark alley, be cautious.
3. *Walking in a dark alley, be cautious.*
4. Walking in a dark alley, you should be cautious.

Question:
Which one/ones of them is ungrammatical? If so, why?

My gut tells me that No.3 is off, but I can't quite gather why.

To make matters worse, I also feel that No.4 is correct, contradicting my previous sentiment somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When** has two meanings:

1 I visited him **when (specific)** I was in Manchester = at **the** time that; on **the** occasion that

2 I visit him **when (general)** I am in Manchester = **whenever**, at **any** time that; on **any** occasion that

(Meaning 2 also tends towards “**if**”: I sometimes travel to the North. When I am near Manchester I might visit him. ≈ if)

Your examples are all inverted. They are fronted by a type of adverbial – they are all capable of being re-adjusted, which is the test to see if they work.

1. You should be cautious when walking in a dark alley,.
2. Be cautious when walking in a dark alley.
3. Be cautious walking in a dark alley.
4. You should be cautious walking in a dark alley.

For the purpose of your examples, there is no significant difference between “**should be** cautious” and “**be** cautious”

Thus the only examples we need are

1. When walking in a dark alley, be cautious.
2. Walking in a dark alley, be cautious.

And both are acceptable although the context will play a part in deciding which is most appropriate.